# Problem with indexing in a monotone sequence

Tags: python

I want to check whether a list of numbers is monotonic (increasing/decreasing) and return a list of Boolean values. 
I'm ***not allowed*** to use advanced tools like: *all*, *zip*, *np*, etc... but I can use loops.

I think my code is not working because `i + 1` goes out of range in the end of the list.

What should I do? Which index should I use? How can I make sure the condition applies to every `i`?

```py
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    if (num_list[i] <= num_list[i+1]):  # strictly
        y = True
    else:
        y = False

    if (num_list[i] >= num_list[i+1]):  # decreasing
        z = True
    else:
        z = False

    list = [y,z]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change mechanics of your function only where necessary:

```
def my_func(num_list):

    # 1-element list needs separate treatment
    if len(num_list)==1:
        return [True, True]

    # here you should init y and z
    # at the beginning you assume num_list is non-decreasing
    y = True
    # at the beginning you assume num_list is non-increasing
    z = True

    # now you check for all but the last element whether y and z maintain
    for i in range(len(num_list)-1):

        # verify need to change y
        # is num_list indeed non-decreasing?
        if (num_list[i] <= num_list[i+1]):
            pass
        else:
            y = False

        # verify need to change z
        # is num_list indeed non-increasing?
        if (num_list[i] >= num_list[i+1]):
            pass
        else:
            z = False

    return [y,z]
```

Tests:

```
>>> my_func([1,2,3])
[True, False]

>>> my_func([2,2,2])
[True, True]

>>> my_func([3,2,1])
[False, True]

>>> my_func([1,2,1])
[False, False]
```

Comment: Why do I have to init the z and y ?

Comment: If you don't initialise them as `True`, then the function could never return `True`; there's no other place in the code that assigns them as `True`.

Comment: @tibetish Yes, otherwise your function will report non-decreasing/non-increasing pattern for the last pair of elements. The element-wise verification, as proposed by you, should allow only switching y and z from True to False.

Comment: To explain intuitively, if you need to check that everything satisfies some condition, then when you check them one-by-one, if you see one which fails the condition then you know the answer is `False`, but if you see one which passes the condition then you *don't* know the answer is `True` because there might be a different one which failed. So it's logically incorrect to assign `True` in the loop on the basis of checking just one element.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SO community.

One way to find out if the numbers are increasing or decreasing is to find out the difference between adjacent numbers, a crude way of finding the differential of the numbers. Here is my code, it finds the difference between the numbers in the list then figures out if the numbers are growing or reducing.

```
myList=[1,2,3,8,17,29,30]
diffList=[]
increasingValue=False
for i in range(len(myList)-1):
    diffList.append(myList[i]-myList[i+1])
#print(diffList)

upDirection=True
directionSwitch=False
if(diffList[0]<0):
    upDirection=False

for item in diffList:

    if(item<0 and upDirection==True):
        directionSwitch=True

    if(item>0 and upDirection==False):
        directionSwitch=True

if(directionSwitch):
    print("Non Monotonic")
```